# Why is “I pray” a response to “thank you” in many languages?

Tags: semantics, comparative-linguistics, meaning

I noticed that “I pray” is used as a response to “thank you” in many languages.

For example,

**Turkish**

> Teşekkür ederim. (“I thank.”)

> Rica ederim. (“I pray (or make a request).”)

**Italian**

> Ti ringrazio. (“I thank you.”)

> Prego. (“I pray.”)

**Croatian**

> Hvala ti. (“Thank you.”)

> Molim. (“I pray.”)

What is the origin of this and how is prayer related to telling someone that they are welcome?

Comment: German too. "Danke - Bitte." I suspect it's because "pray" is associated with "please", as in "Please/Pray don't mention it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [publication by “La Crusca per voi”](http://nencioni.sns.it/fileadmin/template/allegati/QuesitiRisposte/1995_11/1995_11_Risposta_7.pdf) where a correspondent asked the [Accademia della Crusca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accademia_della_Crusca) why “prego” is used in this manner in Italian. The response to that question was written by [linguist Giovanni Nencioni](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Nencioni).

I will provide an English translation below.

> The word *prego* after *grazie* is characteristic of courtesy. I would like to know how it entered into use and if it has a connection to prayer.

> There is no doubt that the verb *pregare* [to pray] originally had, and continues to have in appropriate contexts, a religious meaning. But we need not attribute that  denotation to simple human rapport as well: even mortals *si pregano* [are prayed to, are beseeched], and in that case the meaning of the verb, strong or weak as it may be, sheds the sacral character that characterizes the appeal to divinity.
> The attenuation or semantic emptying of sacred expressions is a widespread fact: when the Romans exclaimed *mehercules* they did not intend to invoke the deified hero Hercules, but to affirm energetically: *indeed! of course!*. When I extract old expressions from memory like *per Giove!* [by Jupiter!], *per Bacco!* [by Bacchus!], I express surprise, resistance, or even enthusiasm; I certainly do not call into question two mythological divinities. I remember hearing from atheists with various degrees of emotion *Madonna!* [Mary!] *Perdio*! [for God's sake], without realizing a possible contradiction. The contradiction effectively did not exist, because these expressions were reduced to simple interjections, that is, utterances of voice aimed at expressing a state of mind, therefore devoid of contextual reference.
> While not an exclamation, the first person form of the present indicative of the verb *pregare* is a courteous form of communication, and is registered as a word by itself in modern dictionaries.

In the rest of his response, Nencioni quotes the definition of the word “prego” in various dictionaries and discusses the nuances of its meaning. So, I did not translate that part.

Answer (score 1):

There is also French "merci" - "je vous en prie". Given that French was for a long time the language of courtly culture I would assume - until proven otherwise - that other languages have borrowed this manner of speaking from French.

As for the “how” and the “why”, I would guess:

“merci” = (I pray that God might grant you) mercy

“je vous en prie” = I pray (that he will grant) of it to you (as well).

Comment: What is the word-for-word translation of "je vous en prie"? Can you also provide the singular/informal version of it, since my examples were written like that?

Comment: @hb20007. Yes,, you can say "je t'en prie" (familiar) Literally: I to-you of-it pray.

Comment: Is this a common expression? I knew of "de rien", which I assume is more popular. If so, is it plausible to say that the other languages borrowed it from French?

Comment: @hb20007. The borrowing, or rather calquing, would have been a long time ago.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's calquing. So was this expression popular in French in the past?

Comment: Danish also has _åh, jeg beder_ ‘oh, I pray’, which is very old-fashioned and falutes quite high.

Answer (score 0):

I believe commenter Luke Sawczak is correct. It is short for "Please, don't mention it," or perhaps something like "I pray that you will think no more of it." The speaker is requesting that the thanker not feel obligated.